# Prometheus not scraping Dapr metrics

Tags: prometheus, grafana, dapr

I have set up prometheus for Dapr metrics in Docker Compose but I'm not getting my Grafana dashboards to populate. I think its because Prometheus is not scraping Dapr metric port localhost:9090. See my configs below:

Docker Compose

prometheus:
image: prom/prometheus:latest
ports:
- "9090:9090"
volumes:
- ./prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml

grafana:
image: grafana/grafana:8.3.3
container_name: grafana
ports:
- "3000:3000"
volumes:
- ./grafana/dashboards.yml:/etc/grafana/provisioning/dashboards/rabbitmq.yaml
- ./grafana/datasources.yml:/etc/grafana/provisioning/datasources/prometheus.yaml
- ./grafana/dashboards:/dashboards
- ./grafana-plugins:/var/lib/grafana/plugins:rw

prometheus.yml

global:
scrape_interval: 15s
scrape_timeout: 10s

alerting:
alertmanagers:

- static_configs:

  - targets:

global 'evaluation_interval'.
rule_files:

scrape_configs:
scraped from this config.

- job_name: 'prometheus'
  static_configs:

  - targets: ['localhost:9090']
- job_name: 'dapr'
  scrape_interval: 5s
  static_configs:

  - targets: ['localhost:9090']
- job_name: 'cadvisor'
  static_configs:

  - targets: ['cadvisor:8080']
    labels:
    alias: 'cadvisor'

[Grafana datasource screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VN2vq.png)

I tried everything I know and setup the dapr datasource in Grafana pointing to http://prometheus:9090 The above configs are exactly the way I am running it. I was expecting to see the Dapr metric dashboards to be fully populated with data but it's saying NO DATA

grafana-sidecar-dashboard.json

sample setup

```
{
  "annotations": {
    "list": [
      {
        "builtIn": 1,
        "datasource": "-- Grafana --",
        "enable": true,
        "hide": true,
        "iconColor": "rgba(0, 211, 255, 1)",
        "limit": 100,
        "name": "Annotations & Alerts",
        "showIn": 0,
        "type": "dashboard"
      }
    ]
  },
  "editable": true,
  "gnetId": null,
  "graphTooltip": 0,
  "id": 3,
  "iteration": 1607134134143,
  "links": [],
  "panels": [
    {
      "collapsed": false,
      "datasource": "dapr",
      "gridPos": {
        "h": 1,
        "w": 24,
        "x": 0,
        "y": 0
      },
      "id": 16,
      "panels": [],
      "title": "Health monitor",
      "type": "row"
    },
    {
      "cacheTimeout": null,
      "datasource": "dapr",
      "description": "This shows the uptime
```